# Highlight entire method scope in Xcode when on a line

Tags: xcode10

When on a particular line in a method ( after doing a find in project ), how can the entire method scope containing that line be selected so we know which method the line belongs to, and what all code is being executed for this method?

Comment: Needless to say, but if you can’t immediately see which method you’re in when glancing at your code, it may need refactoring. E.g., if you are writing Swift, I might suggest using [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) and it will warn you when your methods are longer than what might otherwise be considered best practice. When you first use it, you may have a WTF moment, but bear with it (and/or tweak your `.swift.yml` to something more practical) and you’ll end up with cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the jump bar. It always shows you which method you’re in.

[image]

Also, you can press <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>◀︎</kbd> and it will collapse/fold the current method. But you’ll lose precisely which line you were at before you did that, but you’ll see precisely which method you are in.

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode v10 you are able

1. <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> and select necessary scope(and scroll if you need)

[image]

2. <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + click by brace like `{`

[image]